# Android: Set font family to textview before inflate xml file

Tags: android, android-inflate

I want set `font family` to `Textview`

But i want this action before load `xml`

> My code :

```
for(int i=0;i++;i<100000){    
    final View addNew = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.post, null);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) addNew.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    txtTitle.setText("" + i);
    txtTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"tahoma.ttf"));
}
```

This code it takes time 15-16 seconds

But if i not use `setTypeface` takes time 2-3 seconds

Comment: what you are create a rocket of textviews >>>  why you need `100000 TextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using third party libraries, I recommend you to try [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy). You can find everything you need on the GitHub page, it's really easy to use.

You just need to set it up in your Application class and Activity classes, you put your fonts in the assets folder, and then you can use the fonts from XML, like this:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the binding. Look at the [link](http://www.androidgig.com/setting-custom-font-through-xml-with-databinding/)